# why can't I render a state as a list in react.js? displayed side by side

Tags: reactjs, object, material-ui, state, array.prototype.map

I'm going crazy trying to render an object in react, (Im using material UI)  I have set an onChange in my state claves and valor for two textfield with ui material, everything works correctly, in an add(guardar) button I have set another state that saves those states is guardar and render in accordion material ui, until there Everything works perfect, when I render my guardar state, the Pregunta is rendered correctly without problems, the problem I have is with Respuesta that I make a .map and it is displayed fine but not as I want, I would like it to be displayed one below the other as inside a -li- tag, or whatever just shows one below the other, but shows one next to the other, I already tried anyway and I can't find the solution, leave my code below, sorry the mess is my first question here

```js
const [claves, setClaves] = useState([{ Pregunta: '' }]);
  const [valores, setValores] = useState([{ Respuesta: '' }]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [guardar, setGuardar] = React.useState([{ Pregunta: '', Respuesta: [], Counter: 0 }]);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChangeInput = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const lista = [...valores];
    lista[i][name] = value;
    setValores(lista);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setClaves({
      ...claves,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      id: claves.id + 1,
    });
    console.log(claves);
  };

  const handleAddFields = () => {
    setValores([...valores, { Respuesta: '' }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveFields = (i) => {
    const lista = [...valores];
    lista.splice(i, 1);
    setValores(lista);
  };

  const handleChangePanel = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log('enviar');
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setGuardar([
      ...guardar, {
        Pregunta: claves.Pregunta,
        Respuesta: valores.map((el) => el.Respuesta),
        Counter: count,
      }]);
    const counter = count + 1;
    const panels = `panel${counter}`;
    setCount(panels);
    setClaves({ Pregunta: '' });
    setValores([{ Respuesta: '' }]);
  };
```

```js
return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} columns={2}>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            name="Pregunta"
            label="Pregunta"
            variant="outlined"
            value={claves.Pregunta}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          { valores.map((valor, i) => (
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
            <div key={i}>
              <TextField
                name="Respuesta"
                label="Respuesta"
                variant="outlined"
                value={valor.Respuesta}
                onChange={(e) => handleChangeInput(e, i)}
              />
              <IconButton
                disabled={valores.length === 1}
                onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(i)}
              >
                -
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                onClick={handleAddFields}
              >
                +
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          )) }
          <Button
            className={classes.button}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Agregar

          </Button>
        </form>
      </Grid>
      <Grid xs={1}>
        <Paper style={{ maxHeight: 1000, width: 500, overflow: 'auto' }}>
          {guardar.map((el) => (
            <Accordion expanded={expanded === el.Counter} onChange={handleChangePanel(el.Counter)}>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
              >
                <Typography sx={{ width: '33%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
                  {el.Pregunta}
                </Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <ul>
                  <li>{el.Respuesta}</li>
                </ul>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          ))}
          <Button onClick={handleSave}>registrar</Button>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

try this on console but i cant render yet shows the same

```js
let perro = {
  nombre: "Scott",
  color: "Negro",
  macho: true,
  edad: 5
};

for (let clave in perro){
  console.log(perro[clave]);
}
/*
"Scott"
"Negro"
true
5
*/
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, only include relevant code, that way you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i solved with this

```js
<AccordionDetails>
                <ul>
                  {(() => {
                    const ans = [];
                    const b = el.Respuesta;
                    for (const clave in b) {
                      ans.push(<li>{b[clave]}</li>);
                    }
                    return ans;
                  })()}
                </ul>
              </AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).